# Are VSTS Service Principals impacted by the Azure AD signing key roll over

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, ms-release-management

We have a VSTS Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint that uses a Service Principal to connect to Azure.  This service principal was created manually. I was wondering if this service principle is impacted by the Azure AD signing key roll over and whether it will handle it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a service principal created through VSTS, there shouldn't be a problem. If it's created another way, you'll want to check this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/) from the Azure team about the rollover.